# Is my useEffect used correctly in fetching the weather data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, axios

```
import React,{ useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const App = () => {

  const [ countries, setCountries ] = useState([])
  const [ search, setSearch ] = useState('')
  const [ weather, setWeather ] = useState({})
  const [ capital, setCapital ] = useState('')

  const api_key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY

  const searchedCountries = countries.filter(country =>
    country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
      .then( response => {
        setCountries(response.data)
      })
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${api_key}&query=${capital}`

      axios
      .get(url)
      .then(response => {
        setWeather(response.data)
        console.log('logged weather', response.data)
        console.log('capital inside: ', capital)
      })
    
  },[search])

  console.log(searchedCountries)

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    setSearch(event.target.value)

    if(searchedCountries.length === 1){
      setCapital(searchedCountries[0].capital[0])
      console.log('capital is set', capital)
    }
    else
      setCapital('')
  }

  const handleShow = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setSearch(event.target.value)
  }

  if(searchedCountries.length > 10){
    return(
      <>
        <div>
          find countries
          <input value = {search} onChange = {handleSearch} />  
        </div>
        <p>Too many matches, specify another filter</p>
      </>
    )
  }else{
    if(searchedCountries.length === 1){
      const languages = Object.keys(searchedCountries[0].languages)
      console.log(typeof weather, weather)

      return(
        <>
          <div>
            find countries
            <input value = {search} onChange = {handleSearch} />  
          </div>
          <h1>{searchedCountries[0].name.common}</h1>
          <p>capital {searchedCountries[0].capital[0]}</p>
          <p>population {searchedCountries[0].population}</p>
          <h2>languages</h2>
          <ul>
            {languages.map(language => 
              <li key = {language}>{searchedCountries[0].languages[language]}</li>)}
          </ul>
          <img src= {searchedCountries[0].flags.png} alt= 'flag' />
          <h2>Weather in {searchedCountries[0].capital[0]}</h2>
          {/* <p><strong>temperature: </strong> {weather.current.temperature}  Celcius</p> */}
        </>
      )
    }else{
      return(
        <>
          <div>
            find countries
            <input value = {search} onChange = {handleSearch} />  
          </div>
          {searchedCountries.map( (country, index) => {
            return(
              <div key = {country.name.official}>{country.name.common}
                <button onClick = {handleShow} value = {country.name.common} >show</button>
              </div>
            )
          })}

        </>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default App
```

For example:
I typed in "fin",
[image: Fin is typed on search input]
The object is still empty.
After typing "finl",
[image: Finl is type on search input]
The weather variable contains the weather data on Helsinki.(My monthly usage has reached its limit that why the weather.success of the example picture has a value of false.

If I uncommented the commented line in my code, the app crashes after you typed in "fin."

I want to use the data in the weather API for this app without running into bugs.

Can you help me regarding this problem.
I am a beginner programmer learning react, and react`s interaction to an API.

Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

`weather` is an empty object on the initial render:

```
const [ weather, setWeather ] = useState({});
```

So attempting to access more deeply into the object will throw an error.

Example:

```
weather                     // {}
weather.current             // undefined
weather.current.temperature // error, cannot access X of undefined
```

## Solution

1. You can either provide valid initial initial state for what you are accessing so an error isn't thrown for undefined/null accesses:

   ```
    const [ weather, setWeather ] = useState({ current: {} });
   ```

   Note that you may still need to also do the following to ensure you don't have undefined/null accesses on any subsequent render.
2. Use Optional Chaining/Guard Clauses to protect against undefined/null accesses.

   - Optional Chaining: `weather?.current?.temperature`
   - Guard Clauses: `weather && weather.current && weather.current.temperature`

Comment: Also, another concern is, input seems to be delay in one character. why is that?

Comment: @spademarck React state updates are asynchronously processed. If you are logging the state right after enqueueing it you'll see the unupdated state.

Comment: What can I do to get rid of that delay. Is it better if I didn't use useState for my variables?

Comment: @spademarck Which input/state is delayed? I'm poring over your code again and trying to understand why you have both a `search` and a `capital` state. `search` is the dependency for a `useEffect` hook but isn't referenced, and instead, `capital` is used in the GET request. Can you clarify what you are referring to specifically?

Comment: I have search to capture the value of the input element, and capital to have the value capital value for the URL in the second useEffect.

Comment: @spademarck So is it that `searchedCountries` is a render cycle behind since `search` state hasn't updated yet? You should move the `if (searchedCountries.length === 1) { .....` logic into a separate `useEffect` hook with a dependency on `searchedCountries` (you'll have to memoize `searchedCountries` OFC, and use `capital` as the dependency for that second `useEffect` hook that is making the GET request with `capital` parameter.

Comment: is the second useEffect will surely fire once, even if capital is not set?

Comment: How to stop the default firing of useEffect? And fire only once a certain variable has changed in value?

Comment: @spademarck All React hooks are called on each render, it's up to you to place any side-effects under a condition. You can also use a React ref to track the initial render if you want an effect to run on all but the initial render.

Comment: My concern is, at the first render, surely, the value of capital is ''. and the second useEffect will fire. It will HTTP GET with an invalid URL because capital is still empty. What's the best solution for that?

Comment: @spademarck Use `capital` as a dependency so the effect callback is only invoked when the value of `capital` updates (*other than the initial render*), and don't make the GET request if the value of `capital` isn't ready yet.